# Why can't I upload to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

It says it can't sync the files I am uploading. The error is that it is being rejected by the server. Do you know the solution to this? 
My internet connection is open and I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you log into your account on their webpage?

Comment: yes I can login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Solution 1: Unlink it from the other computer and relink it again [(source)](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=14737&replies=6#post-91854)
- Solution 2: Delete the folder manually on the other machine [(source)](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=13844&replies=2#post-87395)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have used up the capacity. Delete some files that you don't need any more and try again.